# How to make custom JSON decoder for Symfony Entity class?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, serialization

I have Category Entity class which has self-reference to parent. Like this:

```
id
parent
title
description
...
```

I have Normalizer class that encodes object into JSON like this:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "parent": 1,
    "title": "Sports",
    "description": "Sports news." 
}
```

Now I want to generate Entity class when I do POST request in the form like normalizer.

Can I generate entity class from format like this and how? I want to do POST request in the JSON format to create Entity in the REST service.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the form of Symfony. It's better in many ways than denormalizer IHMO

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
$entity = new Entity();
$form = $this->createForm(EntityType::class, $entity, [
    'method' => Request::METHOD_POST
]);
$form = $form->submit($data);

if (!$form->isValid()) {
    return new JsonResponse('Some error in the form', 400);
}

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();

return $this->json($entity, Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: So if I use this approach, will my Entity class get usable reference to parent from my previous example? Will I get generated object that I can persist for instance? The parent is only the ID of the parent entity.